# type mismatch with method returning Unit

Tags: scala

I am completely new to Scala and cannot find clear info on this.

I have this object:

```
object pc { 
  val stack = new Stack[Lattice]
  def top(): Lattice = stack.top
  def pop() = stack.pop
  def push(lev: Lattice) =
    if (stack.isEmpty) stack push lev
    else stack.push(lev(pc.top))            
}
```

But when I try to pop using `pc.pop()`, I get a type mismatch requiring that I need to return a type from a different class in the program although finds type `Lattice`. Example of a call:

```
case If(e, t1, t2) ⇒ {
  val v = eval(e)
  if ( v.T ) {
    pc.push(v.myLevel.⊔(pc.top()))  
    eval( t1 )
    pc.pop()
  } else {
    pc.push(v.myLevel.⊔(pc.top()))
    eval(t2)
    pc.pop()
  }
}
```

here is the exact error when i try to use pop

```
interpreter.scala:127: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ScalaObject
 required: cs162.miniJS.values.Storable
    pc.pop()
```

Comment: Your formatting could really use some work, and I don't think there is enough info here to solve your problem. (i.e., what's the full case expression)

Comment: I tried to fix this as much as possible, but the appropriate import for `Stack` as well as the definition of `Lattice` and `If` are missing.

Comment: I think there's probably an error in whatever surrounds that `case` statement.

Comment: You should always put the error message itself. It is telling you something, and most likely what you need is an explanation of _why_ it is telling you that, but we don't know what that is, do we?

Answer (score 1):

Immutable `Stack`'s `pop` returns tail. `def pop() = if (stack.nonEmpty) { val top = stack.top; stack.pop; Some(val) } else None` should fix it. Or use mutable one.

Comment: If it is an immutable stack, doing `stack.pop` won't change the stack, so that needs fixing as well.

Comment: @ `Daniel C. Sobral` I've tried to get with a uniform solution, for retrieving of elements, that will look the same for mutable and immutable stacks - but only found yet undocumented `def
pop2: (A, Stack[A])` in `immutable.Stack`, am I right ?

Comment: The interfaces are different enough that I don't think striving for code that will work for both is worthwhile.

Comment: hmm in 
def pop() = { if (stack.nonEmpty) { val top = stack.top; stack.pop; Some(val) else None }
there is a missing }. not sure where it goes. I am completely new to scala/functional, sorry for the extremely basic questions.